# Access Azure WebApp with Powershell {"message":"Missing id token. Unauthorized."}

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, web-applications, token

I have created an WebApp in Azure with Azure Authentication enabled. I want to access to this web app using client secret as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60040787/how-to-access-azure-webapp-via-powershell-using-client-secret).

So I used the same script as in the answer but I have an error on the last invoke-RestMethod :

`invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"Missing id token. Unauthorized."}`

How to fix this issue ? FYI My `$authenticationToken` at the end is

```
authenticationToken : eyJhbGci...
user                : @{userId=sid:dcc5f...7f37ec9}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the post that you link to, you use **grant_type=client_credentials**, meaning that you use the **clients credentials flow**.

Using this flow, you have **no id-token** because there is no user involved. This flow/grant-type is only for **machine-to-machine communication.**

Also, important about id-token (if you are using the code flow), you are not supposed to pass the Id-token to other services. If you receive one, then you typically use it to create a local user session.